# How do I get rid of Python Jupyter notebook error: 404 GET /nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main.js

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

> Sys: Macbook 2012 
>   Python: Python 3.5.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
>   Anaconda: conda 4.2.13

I am having issues using notebook extensions (nbextensions) in Jupyter notebook and don't know how to resolve the issue. I would ultimately like to use the nbextensions which are not showing on my Jupyter Notebook toolbar despite installing and reinstalling several times (using pip and/or conda) and removing and reinstalling anaconda altogether.  The exact symptoms, with a linked log follow.

*My error message*: 404 GET /nbextensions/nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main.js

**Goal**: I just want to use notebook extensions again :-(

**Summary of Symptons**

- I cannot use notebook extensions. The buttons don't show up on my
  page for nbpresent and when I try to use the `conda packages`
  extension, I get an error. (screen shot below)
- I have multiple nbextension folders; not sure if I should delete
  something (screen shot below)
- I tried to completely remove my `anaconda` install and reinstall;
  didn't work tried pip uninstall of jupyter and conda remove of
  jupyter but did not change this problem
- `jupyter_path` has several different paths as an output. I'm not sure
  if that is a problem but maybe it is. I don't know what to delete

**Here are the details and screen shots; any help appreciated**

I placed my [log file from launching jupyter notebook with debug here](https://gist.github.com/linwoodc3/eaf150242c2680e2aee8c9602f5febda#file-jupyternotebookdebug-log-L56)

Here is my output of jupyter_path:

```python
>>> from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_path
>>> print(jupyter_path())
['/Users/linwood/Library/Jupyter', '/Users/linwood/anaconda3/share/jupyter', '/usr/local/share/jupyter', '/usr/share/jupyter']
```

If this helps, here's the jupyter I'm using when I'm not in an environment:

```bash
$ which jupyter
/Users/linwood/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

Now the screen shots:

**Multiple nbextension folders**
[image: multiple nbextensions]

**conda packages error**
[image: conda packages error]

**Jupyter_path printout**
[image: jupyter path]

**EDIT**

As requested, the javascript console log. I apologize if this is the wrong thing, but I used the "Developer Tools" console of the Chrome browser to record the javascript activity as the page reloaded.  Here is the info (picture of errors below too):

```
2. Network(X) Basics (Student).ipynb:119 loaded custom.js
default.js:48 Default extension for cell metadata editing loaded.
rawcell.js:82 Raw Cell Format toolbar preset loaded.
slideshow.js:43 Slideshow extension for metadata editing loaded.
menubar.js:240 actions jupyter-notebook:find-and-replace does not exist, still binding it in case it will be defined later...
MenuBar.bind_events @ menubar.js:240
MenuBar @ menubar.js:55
(anonymous) @ main.js:102
execCb @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1690
check @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:865
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:131
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1190
each @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:56
emit @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1189
check @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:940
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1140
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:131
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1190
each @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:56
emit @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1189
check @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:940
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1177
init @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:783
callGetModule @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1204
completeLoad @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1604
onScriptLoad @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1711
utils.js:59 load_extensions ["nbpresent/js/nbpresent.min", "nb_conda/main", "nb_anacondacloud/main", "jupyter-js-widgets/extension"]
utils.js:36 Loading extension: nbpresent/js/nbpresent.min
utils.js:36 Loading extension: nb_anacondacloud/main
require.js?v=6da8be3…:1952 GET http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/nbpresent/js/nbpresent.deps.min.js.js 
req.load @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1952
load @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1679
load @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:829
fetch @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:819
check @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:851
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1177
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:131
each @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:56
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1114
init @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:783
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1453
require.js?v=6da8be3…:165 Uncaught Error: Script error for "nbpresent-deps"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js?v=6da8be3…:165)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js?v=6da8be3…:1732)
makeError @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:165
onScriptError @ require.js?v=6da8be3…:1732
session.js:54 Session: kernel_created (ac540fe3-f39d-4a3d-80c5-265638fb8811)
kernel.js:453 Starting WebSockets: ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/445b6828-66f3-4312-a79f-3c4473345579
kernel.js:100 Kernel: kernel_connected (445b6828-66f3-4312-a79f-3c4473345579)
kernel.js:100 Kernel: kernel_ready (445b6828-66f3-4312-a79f-3c4473345579)
utils.js:36 Loading extension: nb_conda/main
utils.js:36 Loading extension: jupyter-js-widgets/extension
extension.js:88 loaded widgets
manager-base.js:195 Widget backend and frontend versions are compatible
```

[image]

Comment: From the last picture, on the right on the toolbar, it seems that some nbextensions are loaded (nbpresent?, code_prettify?). Is that right? Could you post the javascript console log, in order to see if the nbextensions are requested (and which) and if some are loaded?

Comment: I added the log as requested.

Comment: For anyone following, or anyone who experiences this same problem, you can follow the fix/progress here: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/489#issuecomment-272496673.  I will post the fix on this stackoverflow if/when we get to it.

Answer (score 4):

Install nbextensions

Solution a) create new env, activate, install nbextensions, install js/css file, start jupyter

```
conda create --name py39 python=3.9
conda activate py39
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter-notebook
```

[image]

solution b) https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1012#issuecomment-309448477

Indeed if you would like only get rid of 404 Get error

```
jupyter nbextension list
```

You will see output

```
    Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /home/your_user/.jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main disabled
      contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main disabled
      hinterland/hinterland disabled
      code_prettify/code_prettify disabled
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension disabled
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main  enabled 
     - Validating: problems found:
     - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
```

Go to each main configuration in the files and change it to false. I found all files in **~/anaconda3/etc/jupyter/nbconfig**

Specifically **tree.json** in my case

```
nano tree.json
```

Output

```
{
  "load_extensions": {
    "nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main": true
  }
}
```

After changing true to **false** you will get rid of 404

Answer (score 1):

It can simply be the fact that you have restarted jupyter but not your browser that is keeping an old session reference, see: https://github.com/jupyter-server/kernel_gateway/issues/320#issuecomment-494087267

**Else**

On my side I had a lot of 404 errors too like yours.

Running `jupyter nbextension list` shown that one of them was not properly installed :

```
Known nbextensions:
  config dir: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/Book2/etc/jupyter/nbconfig
    notebook section
      bqplot/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      ipyvolume/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
      ...
      pydeck/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X pydeck/extension
      jupyter-js-widgets/extension  enabled 
      - Validating: OK
```

SO I've removed the package in trouble : `mamba/conda remove pydeck` and it solved it.

You can try to reinstall it, of course

Answer (score -1):

In the browser remove everything post tree in the URL. For example:

```
http://localhost:8888/tree
```

and it would work. Port number:`8888` where the Jupiter notebook is running on.

Answer (score -2):

I have been struggling with a particular (useful) nbextension, Table of Contents (2).  Symptom: I set TOC(2) to load in the nbextensions configuration tab, but no TOC loads.

I often (but not always) see

> 404 GET /nbextensions/toc2.js

on the server console.

Workaround:  break the notebook into pieces.  The extension seems to work fine if the notebook is small enough.